# Remap ctrl-h to ctrl-b o in bash for tmux

Tags: bash, tmux

How do I remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> in bash? This is for switching panes in tmux.

I tried using

```
bind '"\C-h":"\C-bo"'
```

but all it did was print "o" in the terminal.

Comment: You can't do it this way because tmux controls bash and not the other way around. You should rebind it in tmux instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind `C-h` in the root key table in `tmux`, so that you don't need to type the  prefix first.

```
bind-key -n C-h select-pane -t :.+  # Same command prefix+o is bound to
```